# What do commands in bash get with '' as argument

Tags: c, bash

I'm recreating Bash in C, and I'm trying to figure out what argument does the command get with empty quotes. I'm executing commands with `execve`.

I noticed that

```
echo 123''456
```

just prints out `123456`, but if you put

```
char *echo_args[] = {"echo", "123", "", "456", NULL};
execve("/bin/echo", echo_args, NULL);
```

the output is `123 456` with space between, so I figured out that the only way to remove that space is by not putting the empty string argument in `execve`; but then if you do `grep ''`, grep clearly gets some argument because it's not acting same as if it was just `grep`, so what I'm asking is why does `echo` not get an empty string as its argument and `grep` does?

Comment: `echo 123''456` -- if one disables the `echo` builtin -- turns into `execve("/bin/echo", {"echo", "123456", NULL})` -- the shell completely consumes the quotes, they don't survive parsing.

Comment: `execve` does not invoke `bash` or any shell whatsoever. It is invoking the passed executable "directly"

Comment: If you ran `echo 123 '' 456` or `echo 123 "" 456` in your shell, **then** you'd get the same argv as your proposed line of C code.

Comment: The output from that should have **two** spaces between `123` and `456`. Did you look carefully?

Comment: BTW, if you're trying to implement a shell, don't go from experimentation or rough understanding -- read, and follow, [the exact letter of the specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html).

Comment: Simply speaking, in the first case, the `echo` sees 1 argument and in your `execve` approach, the `echo` sees 3 arguments.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I've resolved it. It was a parsing error, and the problem was that I relied too much on ChatGPT. It told me that every quote is a new token. Now, I'm just merging it into one token when it's not separated by spaces, tabs, redirections, pipes, and all those things.

Comment: Implementing a simple shell is probably a good exercise; but reimplementing all of Bash probably isn't. Also, if you want to implement a basic Bourne-like shell, understanding its syntax is pretty much a requirement. You have to start somewhere, of course, but it's not hard to find beginner documentation for how quoting works in most Unix-like shells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the shell command `echo 123''456`, the `''`s don't turn into anything; they're completely removed during parsing and not passed to `echo` at all.

This is because the shell parses quotes *character-by-character*; `123''456` concatenates the unquoted string `123`, a single-quoted empty string, and an unquoted string `456` **into a single argument**.

By contrast, in `grep ''`, the `''` is separated by spaces from any other arguments, preventing that empty string from being concatenated into (and thus subsumed by) anything else.

---

To execute `echo` from bash the same way your C code does, with three separate arguments beyond `argv[0]`, you can run:

```bash
enable -n echo  # turn off bash-builtin echo so we use the one from /bin
echo 123 '' 456
```

Notice the spaces between `''` and the surrounding arguments; these spaces are shell syntax, causing the empty string to be its own argument rather than being appended to something non-empty and thus disappearing.

Comment: Similarly, `grep''` is exactly equivalent to `grep` (as well as `'grep'`, `'g''r''e''p'`, etc ad naus.)